# do until user input yes/no

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a simple `do..until` loop and it does not work:

```
$yesNo = Read-Host -Prompt 'Do you want to add alternative DNS names or IPs into Certificate? Y/N: '

do {
    $dnsipname = Read-Host -Prompt "Please input DNS or IP as dns=alternativeCNname or ip=ipName: "
    Write-Output "$dnsipname" 
    $strQuit = Read-Host " do you want to add another DNS? (Y/N)"
    do {
        $dnsipname = Read-Host -Prompt "Please input DNS or IP as dns=alternativeCNname or ip=ipName: "
        Write-Output "$dnsipname" 
        Add-Content D:\Scripts\expiringCerts\request.inf '`r`n_continue_ = "$dnsipname"'
    } until ($strQuit -eq "Y" -or "y")
} until ($yesNo -eq "Y" -or "y")
```

This one does loop twice only, but it should loop every time I hit `Y` but when I hit `N` or `n` It should break.

Any ideas?

Comment: also `Add-Content D:\Scripts\expiringCerts\request.inf '`r`n_continue_ = "$dnsipname"'` does not write to file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In PowerShell you have basically three options to prompt a user for a yes/no choice.

- The [`Read-Host`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) cmdlet:

  ```
  $msg = 'Do you want to add alternative DNS names or IPs into Certificate? [Y/N]'
  do {
      $response = Read-Host -Prompt $msg
      if ($response -eq 'y') {
          # prompt for name/address and add to certificate
      }
  } until ($response -eq 'n')
  ```

  Use `-like 'y*'` and `-like 'n*'` if you want to ignore trailing characters in the response.
- The [`PromptForChoice()`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx) method:

  ```
  $title   = 'Certificate Alternative Names'
  $msg     = 'Do you want to add alternative DNS names or IPs?'
  $options = '&Yes', '&No'
  $default = 1  # 0=Yes, 1=No

  do {
      $response = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $msg, $options, $default)
      if ($response -eq 0) {
          # prompt for name/address and add to certificate
      }
  } until ($response -eq 1)
  ```
- The [`choice`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732504.aspx) command:

  ```
  $msg = 'Do you want to add alternative DNS names or IPs into Certificate'
  do {
      choice /c yn /m $msg
      $response = $LASTEXITCODE
      if ($response -eq 0) {
          # prompt for name/address and add to certificate
      }
  } until ($response -eq 1)
  ```

Comment: Nice summary. However - I personally don't like user prompts at all. In this particual case I would pass a `string[]` to the script containing all DNS / IPs the consumer wants to add. There is no need for prompts (in my world) ;-)

Comment: thank you! :) it helped me a lot with understanding do-until loops

Comment: @MartinBrandl Prompts do have their uses, although I have to agree that most of the time I prefer being able to pass required information as parameters.

Comment: choice keyword returns the index of choice, starting with 1.

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't need two `do-until` loop. I also would prefer a `do-while` (while he is confirming with `y` or `Y`).

Your string interpolation on the `Add-Content` doesn't work because you are using *single quotes*. I would leverage a format string here:

```
$yesNo = Read-Host -prompt 'Do you want to add alternative DNS names or IPs into Certificate? Y/N: '
if ($yesNo -eq 'y')
{
    do 
    {
        $dnsipname = read-host -prompt "Please input DNS or IP as dns=alternativeCNname or ip=ipName: "
        Write-output "$dnsipname" 
        Add-Content -Path "D:\Scripts\expiringCerts\request.inf" -value ('`r`n_continue_ = "{0}"' -f $dnsipname)
        $strQuit = Read-Host " do you want to add another DNS? (Y/N)"                
    }
    while($strQuit -eq 'y')
}
```

Comment: mmmmm :) thanks, do you know by the any chance why `Add-Content D:\Scripts\expiringCerts\request.inf ('`r`n_continue_ = "{0}"' -f $dnsipname)` does not work?

Comment: try `Add-Content -Path "D:\Scripts\expiringCerts\request.inf" -value ('`r`n_continue_ = "{0}"' -f $dnsipname)`

Comment: I would think `-eq "y"` works fine since it is case insensitive by default. No need for the match operator.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the condition that you are evaluating in the `until` statement  ($strQuit for your example) inside the `do` loop for it to be updated.

Wrapping the `do` loop in an `if` statement also makes the process friendlier to the user as it ask them before continuing to prompt.

```
$dnsipname = read-host -prompt "Please input DNS or IP as dns=alternativeCNname or ip=ipName: "
Write-Output $dnsipname
Add-Content D:\Scripts\expiringCerts\request.inf '`r`n_continue_ = "$dnsipname"'

if ((Read-Host "Do you want to add another DNS or IP? (Y/N)") -eq "Y") {
    do {
        $dnsipname = Read-Host "Please input DNS or IP as dns=alternativeCNname or ip=ipName: "
        Write-output "$dnsipname" 
        Add-Content D:\Scripts\expiringCerts\request.inf '`r`n_continue_ = "$dnsipname"'
        $strQuit = Read-Host "Do you want to add another DNS or IP? (Y/N)"
    }
    until ($strQuit -eq "N")
}
```

Comment: You can mark my answer as accepted, this helps others know your question has been answered and also helps with future searches. Here's how you do it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: As I read your script, it will continue the do loop **until** the user press y or Y, but it should continue as long he is pressing y or Y. Also `$strQuit -eq "Y" -or "y"` will always return `$true` thus its an endless loop.

Comment: @MartinBrandl Good spot, forgot to change it to a while loop!

Comment: Yes, also don't to remove `-or "y"` otherwise he won't be able to get out of the loop....

Comment: Hm, your script don't ask whether he wants to add alternative DNS names, it just performs the action and then ask to add another. you probably have to refactor this as well. Your if statement is obsolete as well....