# Ask confirmation to save the file with Y or N. However its stuck on loop

Tags: powershell

In my script I need to ask confirmation to save the file using Y or N. However, it is stuck in a loop.

```
$ErrorOccured8 = $false
$confirmation = Read-Host "Do you want to save the output to text file? [y/n]"
while ($confirmation -ne "n") {
    if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
        try { 
            $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
            Write-Host ("`Currently saving output to text. Please locate in temp folder.`n") -ForegroundColor darkmagenta

            c:\temp\gsd.exe > c:\temp\$($server)_$(((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).txt
            pause
        } catch {
            Write-Host ("`There has been some error. Kindly locate the file and refresh.`n") -ForegroundColor darkmagenta 
            $ErrorOccured8 = $true
        }
    } else {
        exit
    }
    #$confirmation = Read-Host "Do you want to save the output to text file? [y/n]"
    pause
}

pause
exit
```

Comment: What is the string of `$server`? remove sensitive details of course.

Comment: its for the server name so the output of the textfile is 'servername_date.txt' I am able to output the file by force closing the exe file and triggering y, but if i try doing y, its stuck on loop.

Comment: The `Read-Host` inside your loop is commented out, so `$confirmation` is never changed. If the user enters "y" you get an infinite loop.

Comment: As a side-note, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40890047/1630171) for a more PoSh way of prompting for user confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend removing the while loop and setting a switch.

Your while loop was just constantly attempting to run the `If` statement over and over.

```
$ErrorOccured8 = $false
$confirmation = Read-Host "Do you want to save the output to text file? [y/n]"

switch ($confirmation) {
        "y"
        {
            try { 
               $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
               Write-Host("`Currently saving output to text. Please locate in temp folder.`n") -ForegroundColor darkmagenta 
               c:\temp\gsd.exe > "c:\temp\$($server)_$(((get-date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).txt"
            } catch {
               Write-Host("`There has been some error. Kindly locate the file and refresh.`n") -ForegroundColor darkmagenta 
               $ErrorOccured8=$true
            }
        }

        "n"
        {
            exit
        }
    }
```