# How to go to any specific line in PowerShell during execution

Tags: powershell-2.0

```bsh
if ((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName . -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain -eq "domain.local") {
    # Check with User if she/he wants to continue or not
    Write-Host "Hurray you are in domain.local domain"
    $FirstCondition = Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to continue? If yes please press [Y] else press[N] to discontinue"
    if ($FirstCondition = "Y") {
        # Check if server is pinging or not
        if (Test-Connection -ComputerName . -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
            $NetworkAdapter = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName . -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=$true |
                              Select-Object -Property [a-z]* -ExcludeProperty IPX*,WINS*
            Test-Connection $net.DNSServerSearchOrder[0] -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop
        }
    } else {
        Goto Line:1
    }
}
```

In the `else {Goto Line:1}` part I'm facing an issue, as during execution I need this command to run the first line `if ((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName . -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain -eq "domain.local")` and check if the server is in domain.local domain or not. Please help me find a substitute for `Goto` in PowerShell 2.0.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar for your reply. I was unable to put the code correctly in this blog so have to adjust wihtout any indentation. Yes I know Goto is not used in powershell script so that's why I was searching for substitute of this Goto. I have put in there so that someone can understand what I am really looking for.

Comment: Duplicate of [do until user input yes/no](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40889444/1630171). You want to prompt the user for input in a loop until they select a particular option (and/or a command returns a particular value). There is no need for using `goto` here.

Comment: Hi my query is how can I go to a specific line in a script so that it should start the script from the line where I want to start?

Comment: I'm well aware of what you were asking. I just elected to ignore it, b/c it isn't a sensible thing to do. You don't do things like that in modern programming languages. Please read up on [control flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow).